How to Disable HTTP/2 for Specific Sites in IIS Using PowerShell?
I'm running an IIS web server on Windows Server 2019, and I need to disable HTTP/2 for some specific sites while keeping it enabled for others.
I know that I can disable HTTP/2 globally by setting the following registry keys:
For TLS:
HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters
EnableHttp2Tls (DWORD) = 0

For clear text (non-TLS):
HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters
EnableHttp2Cleartext (DWORD) = 0

However, this approach disables HTTP/2 for all sites on the server. Is there a way to disable HTTP/2 for specific sites or applications in IIS using PowerShell or any other method?
I've looked into the IIS configuration settings but couldn't find an option to control HTTP/2 at the site level.
Any guidance or scripts to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
Environment:
Windows Server 2019
IIS 10
What I've Tried:
Modifying the global registry keys (disables HTTP/2 server-wide)
Searching through IIS site-level settings via PowerShell

By setting -SslFlag property in command, you can achieve your needs, something like below:
New-IISSiteBinding -Name "mySite" -BindingInformation "*:443:" -CertificateThumbPrint "xxxx" -CertStoreLocation "your:\cert\path" -Protocol https -SslFlag "DisableHTTP2"

Simply refer to this doc: New-IISSiteBinding - SslFlag property.
